# google-Diff-Match-Patch doesn't work properly on some file

Tags: java

I m using google-diff-match-patch for comparing to text files.first input is xml file and second input is xml file, first I normalize the text of two file. It works fine for many files but on some file it doesn't work properly,it shoes that the two file is totally different. but in actual it is not like that. my code is :

```
package com.java.contentMatcher;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;
import com.java.diff.diff_match_patch;
import com.java.diff.diff_match_patch.Diff;
import com.java.diff.diff_match_patch.Operation;
public class SGL_ContentMatcher {
public static Properties CONFIG_PROPS;
public static String input_path1, input_path2, compaired_file;
public static String text1 = "";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter  Html Input Directory : ");
    input_path1 = scanIn.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter  XML Input Directory : ");
    input_path2 = scanIn.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter  Output Directory : ");
    compaired_file = scanIn.nextLine();
    LinkedList<File> input_list = (LinkedList<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(input_path1),
            TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    LinkedList<File> output_list = (LinkedList<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(input_path2),
            TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for (Iterator iterator = input_list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        File file = (File) iterator.next();

        for (Iterator iterator2 = output_list.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
            File file2 = (File) iterator2.next();

            String f1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
            String f2 = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file2.getName());

            if (f1.equals("html") && f2.equals("xml")) {
                String filename1, filename2;

                int end = file.getName().lastIndexOf(FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()));
                filename1 = file.getName().substring(0, end);

                end = file2.getName().lastIndexOf(FilenameUtils.getExtension(file2.getName()));
                filename2 = file2.getName().substring(0, end);
                System.out.println(filename1 + "---------------" + filename2);

                if (filename1.equals(filename2)) {

                    System.out.println("file1" + file.getName() + "File2" + file2.getName());
                    // first file
                    xmlInput = xmlInput.replaceAll("\\n+|\\r+|\\t+", " ").replaceAll("<.*?>", " ")
                            .replaceAll("&#[a-zA-Z0-9]+;", " ").replaceAll("&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;", " ")
                            .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

                    String xmlInput2 = FileUtils.readFileToString(file2);

                    xmlInput2 = xmlInput2.replaceAll("\\n+|\\r+|\\t+", " ").replaceAll("<.*?>", " ")
                            .replaceAll("&#[a-zA-Z0-9]+;", " ").replaceAll("&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;", " ")
                            .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

                    diff_match_patch diff = new diff_match_patch();
                    LinkedList<Diff> diffrences = diff.diff_main(xmlInput, xmlInput2);
                    String str = diff.diff_prettyHtml(diffrences);

                    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(compaired_file + File.separator + file.getName()), str);

                    // String text1 = "";
                    String text2 = "";
                    String text3 = "";
                    for (Diff d : diffrences) {
                        if (d.operation == Operation.DELETE) {
                            text1 = text1 + " " + d.text;

                            System.err.println("text1" + text1 + "text2" + text2);
                        } else if (d.operation == Operation.INSERT) {
                            text2 = text2 + " " + d.text;
                            // System.err.println("text1"+text1+"text2"+text2);
                        } else if (d.operation == Operation.EQUAL) {
                            text3 = text3 + " " + d.text;
                        }

                    }
                   text1 = text1 + " ---->" + file2.getName();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(compaired_file + "/UnMatched.txt"), text1);
}

}
```

google-diff match patch api is here:
`https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/downloads/detail?name=diff_match_patch_20121119.zip`
my input link is :
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9sBq5p886c4VC1IOExLZnllcm8`